# How to remove flags from language menu

Tags: php, css, wordpress, plugins, wpml

I am using Betheme and I integrated WPML plugin to translate my website. But I don't want flags on the language menu. Is there any css or code which could turn the flags into languages name in language menu? The language switcher adds the language name into main menu but not in the language menu.

[1]:Language Menu: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C8JG.png

Answer (score 0):

You can customize WPML Language Switchers at **WPML > Languages** page as shown [here](https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/language-setup/language-switcher-options/). Each language switcher type has its own settings, including how it will look.

If bigger customization is needed, WPML also offers [Twig Template files](https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/language-setup/designing-custom-language-switchers-using-template-files/) for this purpose.